# words derived from French that have re-entered French from English

Tags: etymology, french

I am looking for a few examples of words that originated in French (or in Latin and then entered French), entered English and were reimported into French.

Comment: There's a list (work in progress) of them on French Language: http://french.stackexchange.com/a/8285/358

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about words imported **into** French (ELU handles current English words, not the etymology of current French words).

Answer (score 4):

***Challenge***<sup>1</sup>, ***toast***<sup>2</sup> and ***ticket***<sup>3</sup> are some examples of words that entered English from Old French and then re-entered French from English (according to the book "The Story of French" *By Jean-Benoit Nadeau, Julie Barlow*).

<sub><sup>[1](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=challenge&searchmode=none)</sup> ...also "act of laying claim" (to something), from Anglo-French *chalenge*, Old French *chalonge* [etymonline]</sub>

<sub><sup>[2](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=toast&searchmode=none)</sup> "to brown with heat," late 14c., from Old French *toster* "to toast, to grill, roast, burn" (12c.) [etymonline]</sub>

<sub><sup>[3](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ticket)</sup> 1520s, "short note or document," from a shortened form of Middle French *etiquet* "label, note," from Old French *estiquette* "a little note" (late 14c.) [etymonline]</sub>

---

Below is the related passage from the book "The Story of French". It is from a section of the book that talks about the transformation of French language in eighteenth century.

[image]

Comment: Also, bacon (!!) and manager/management.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's barbecue too, from old french barbaque=viande (meat).

Comment: If you're not sure and have no reference, this is really a comment not a full answer.